# Does a magnetic field always have rotational symmetry?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, symmetry, noethers-theorem

Does a magnetic field always have rotational symmetry? If not, would someone mind giving me an example?

Comment: The Earth's magnetic field is also asymmetric. Most real world examples are, except for simple things like permanent magnets or for things like pulsars.https://ase.tufts.edu/cosmos/view_picture.asp?id=998

Comment: Even neutron stars can have asymmetric magnetic fields, for example by developing so called "mountains." See eg https://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.4264.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely not. Here is an map of the magnetic field in the galaxy from Sobey, et al., Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society, Volume 484, Issue 3, April 2019, Pages 3646–3664. As you can see, it has a lot of complex structure and is not rotationally invariant in any sense.

[image: map of galatic field]

Comment: Thanks man, Now i am wondering how they get this kind of data. But that is out of the original question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-Frequency_Array_(LOFAR)#Cosmic_magnetism